# I have no overlayfs driver in /var/lib/docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

My version is Ubuntu 16.04 and kernel version is 4.4.0 generic

I want to use overlayfs driver so I install docker first successfully by the turorial :**http://ciplogic.com/index.php/blog/107-docker-with-overlayfs-on-ubuntu-14-04**

but I found no overlay directory under the **/var/lib/docker/** after installing docker.There is only **aufs** and other directories there.

Here is my docker version:

Client:

Version:      1.12.1

API version:  1.24

Go version:   go1.6.3

Git commit:   23cf638

Built:        Thu Aug 18 05:33:38 2016

OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:

Version:      1.12.1

API version:  1.24

Go version:   go1.6.3

Git commit:   23cf638

Built:        Thu Aug 18 05:33:38 2016

OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Does anyone know any ideas to set up overlay driver in docker ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik it is necessary to tell the docker-daemon explicitly which storage-driver it should use. The necessary switch for that is

```
--storage-driver=overlay
```

For this to work with systemd you need to copy `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service` and change the `ExecStart`-param:

```
root@pc / # cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service 
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --storage-driver=overlay -H fd://
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
# Uncomment TasksMax if your systemd version supports it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this version.
#TasksMax=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes
# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Regards